# How to properly test this kind of timed concurrent processing service?

Tags: java, junit, testng, mockito, timing

I have a service which is used to simulate an IoT hardware component which sends data periodically to a SOAP endpoint:

```
private static final int DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 100 * 1024;

public void simulate(final int samplingFrequencyMs, final int uploadFrequencyMs) {
    // ...
```

This method generates a JSON object every time `samplingFrequencyMs` time passes and calls a SOAP endpoint every time `uploadFrequencyMs` time passes and chunks the generated data into `DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE_IN_BYTES` size chunks.

So for example if `samplingFrequencyMs` is `500` and `uploadFrequencyMs` is `1000` then this method will send 2 generated JSON strings every second to a SOAP endpoint and if the size of the 2 JSON strings is 200 Kbyte then it will send 2 chunks.

There is also a method which stops the simulation:

```
public void stopSimulation() {
    // ...
```

I've written a test for this simulator:

```
@Test
public void shouldSendProperAmountOfChunksWhenInvokingSimulate() throws InterruptedException
{
    // ...

    // when
    underTest.simulate(100, 500);
    Thread.sleep(750);

    underTest.stopSimulation();

    Thread.sleep(500);

    // then
    verify(requestServiceMock, times(EXPECTED_REQUEST_CALL_TIMES)).doRequest(uploadBinary, header);
}
```

but this test fails 1-2 times out of 100 because the service was not invoked `EXPECTED_REQUEST_CALL_TIMES` times so it is not stable. How can I test this when I have to verify the times a method was called but there is timing involved? I used `750` because it is between `500` and `1000` and I thought that this should do the trick but I think there must be some testing best practice for this kind of situation.

Comment: I assume there are producer and consumer threads running within simulate method. If consumer sleeps for 1 sec then collect all and send to soap end point while producers sequentially inserts data in queue in 0.5 secs: we can expect condtions where consumer will only send 1 piece. Calling Thread.sleep(500) guarantees min 500 ms of sleep duration. It can end up waiting more than 500 ms.

Comment: There is a `Timer` which schedules a producer and a consumer task every 500 ms to an `Executor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is abstract away the concept of the system time from your CUT.  A typical approach is to inject a `Clock` object that you can control.  Your real implementation will delegate to the system clock, but within the test you have exact control over what's going on.